# How do I add an entire directory to py2app setup file?

Tags: python, file, directory, include, py2app

Right now I have some example files included in the setup.py file, but what do I do if I want to add the entire directory to DATA_FILES? And my script creates files aswell, so they have to be accessible and be stored together with the others. (I have just started with python so I am sorry if there is a very obvious solution to this!)

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['KeyPass.py']
DATA_FILES = ['kristoffer.txt', 'appicon.png', 'application.png','background-2.png', 'editimg.png', 'resultater.png', 'user.png']
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'appicon.icns',
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your `data_files=DATA_FILES,` line works, but *data_files* does take a list, and it can include 2-element tuples, one of which can be something like:

```
DATA_FILES = [('examples', glob.glob('examples/*.*')),]
```

The first element is a directory name, and the second is a list of files to grab.
This should allow you to add a directory to your setup.py.
The *glob* module allows wildcard access.